# Реализация сложной сортировки на сайте (Node JS + MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, сортировка, теория

Интересует не столько практическая реализация, хотелось бы теоретически разложить все по полочкам.

Хочется сделать что то вроде "многоуровневой" сортировки постов при которой можно будет получить:

1. Сортировка по просмотрам
2. По рейтингу (liked)
3. По скачиваниям (есть к примеру .txt файл который качают, ну или картинка какая то)
4. По комментариям к постам

Это как бы некий первый "слой" сортировки с ним проблем собственно нет и реализовать его не очень сложно. Проблема заключается в более глубокой сортировке в которой будет участвовать параметры.
Сортировать за:

1. День
2. Неделю
3. Месяц
4. Год

По url будет как то так:
При первичном сорте:

```
/view/
/liked/
/comments/
```

При более глубокой сортировке

```
/view/day/
/liked/day/
/comments/day/

/view/week/
/liked/week/
/comments/week/

/view/month/
/liked/month/
/comments/month/
```

Не могу придумать как правильно хранить всю информацию в базе.

Сейчас в голову приходит только следующее:
В коллекции post есть записи, например

```
{
    id: идентификатор,
    title: Название,
    // Далее уже с сортировкой
    view: {month: 100, week: 20, day: 2},
    liked: {month: 50, week: 10, day: 1},
    comments: {month: 40, week: 5, day: 0},
    created: Дата создания поста
}
```

При такой структуре ничего не остается как каждый день кроном или еще как то изменять все записи для пересчета значений просмотров, лайков и т.д.

1. Правильно ли я рассуждаю и справится ли mongodb при обновлении всех записей при большом объеме данных? Ну скажем с 500 000 записей
2. Возможно ли что то попроще сделать?

Comment: Я с такими проблемами (пока) не сталкивался, но, возможно, часть работы надо перекидывать с бд на кэш. Я бы скидывал значения подсчета туда, они бы сами инвалидировались через время, не было бы скачкообразной нагрузки, как при пересчете кроном (правда, если кэширующий сервер упадет, а их всего немного - быть беде).

> Правильно ли я рассуждаю и справится ли mongodb при обновлении всех записей при большом объеме данных? Ну скажем с 500 000 записей

Сейчас меня запинают ногами, но про mongodb я слышал левым ухом, что она блокирует всю бд при записи (в следующем релизе только таблицы).

Comment: Я тоже слышал про блокировку...
Надо будет покумекать на кешем, я пока с ним плохо знаком, в плане реализации.

Ну, а пока накумекал более изящный способ, правда не знаю как в действии он себя поведет, но думаю скачки нагрузки точно снимет:
Вобщем если создать доп. поле с датой последнего обновления у каждой записи, при запросе в базу информации об этой записи делать проверку по дате, если дата последнего обновления отличается от сегодняшней, то можно обновить значения сортировки. 

Думаю это существенно снизит нагрузку, так как будет обновляться только по запросу, а не все скопом.

Comment: Или еще такой вариант:
Создать еще 4 коллекции в которые складывать лайки, просмотры и к каждому полю проставлять дату, как то так:

view: {
    id: ID поста,
    created: Дата просмотра
}

Тогда просто count`ом пробегаться с условием по дате и получать ID записей, ну а затем пачками выбирать их из основной коллекции.

Только куча строк будет, особенно по просмотрам. База будет расти неимоверно быстро.

Вобщем беда, даже и не знаю что делать =(
Подожду еще чуток, может кто уже сталкивался с таким и посоветует что нибудь дельно.